# creating an average score variable

Tags: average, spss

I have a dataset that goes as follows:

an ID then his/hers storenumber then the amount of units they bought there.

What i now need from that dataset is a variable that states the following: x buys per ID (for a specific store) (this score would thus be the same for different id's with the same storenumber) example:

ID 1 and 2 have respectively 3 and 5 buys at store 1. then the variable i want would be (3+5)/2=4 then both ID's would get the variable average buys per ID for ID 1 and 2 is 4.

I just cannot get the above done through spss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to create some fake data to play with:

```
data list list/storeNum IDinstore NumPurchased.
begin data
1 1 3
1 2 5
1 3 7
1 4 9
2 1 4
2 2 8
2 3 12
end data.
```

assuming what you want is the average number of units bought in each store, what you should do is aggregate:

```
AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=storeNum
  /NumPurchased_mean=MEAN(NumPurchased).
```